# animation while drawing a line

Tags: iphone, ios

I am drawing a line between two coordinates using below function now I want to show the rotating animation like line is drawing on one by one point so how can i do that?

```
            x1 = [[xCoordinates objectAtIndex:i]intValue];
            y1 = [[yCoordinates objectAtIndex:i]intValue];

           x2 = [[xCoordinates objectAtIndex:i+1]intValue];
           y2 = [[yCoordinates objectAtIndex:i+1]intValue];
            UIImageView *drawImage = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
            drawImage.frame = self.view.frame;
            [self.view addSubview:drawImage];

            UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size);
            [drawImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
            CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
            CGContextSetLineCap(context, kCGLineCapRound);
            CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 5.0);
            CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, 0.5, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0); 
            CGContextMoveToPoint(context, xBegin, yBegin);
            CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, x1, y1);
            CGContextStrokePath(context);
            drawImage.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
            [drawImage release];
            [UIView commitAnimations];
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample code that might help you to achieve what you want`http://nachbaur.com/blog/core-animation-part-4`.

Comment: It was a good code but not helpful to me bcz i want animation as pixel by pixel when line is drawing between two point

Comment: There are lots of algorithm to get points that's are in between your origin and destination point. I thought you know about that. That's why I have provided only animation code.